# Is the ordering of members of a map, seeming to be by addition, reliable?

Tags: scala, dictionary

When I create an immutable map with a standard call to `Map()` or by concatenating the existing maps created that way, in all my tests I get that traversing its members provides them in the order of addition. That's exactly the way I need them to be sorted, but there's not a word in the documentation about the reliability of the ordering of the members of the map.

So I was wondering whether it is safe to expect the standard Map to return its items in the order of addition or I should look for some other implementations and which ones in that case.

Comment: It's generally not advisable to rely on implementation details. That said, `scala.collection.immutable.Map[A,B]` implements `Iterable[(A,B)]` and not `Seq[(A,B)]`, which would guarantee an order.

Comment: Instead of using a `Map[K,V]` you could use a `Map[K,(V, Int)]` where the `Int` its insertion index. Then call `toSeq` and sort on that field if you need to extract all the pairs as a sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's safe, the order is not preserved starting from 5 elements (Scala 2.9.1):

```
scala> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 5)
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = 
  Map(5 -> 5, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4)
```

With bigger maps the order is completely "random", try `Map((1 to 100) zip (1 to 100): _*)`.

Try [`LinkedHashMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedHashMap.html) for ordered entries and [`TreeMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.html) to achieve sorted entries.

Comment: Yikes! The same is reproducable in 2.10.0-M3. Ok, so to the second part of the question: which implementation would you recommend in my case?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: try [`LinkedHashMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedHashMap.html) for ordered entries and [`TreeMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.html) to achieve sorted entries.

Comment: Thanks, but although `LinkedHashMap` does order the items correctly it is mutable. I know of the immutable `ListMap` which also does the trick but according to [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) it performs awfully. So it looks like I've gotta deal with it or make a custom implementation - right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no promise about the order of `Map`. There is an `OrderedMap` in scalas collection package. The values in that package are ordered by an implicit `Ordering`. As quickfix I recommend you to use a list of keys for the ordering of your Map.

```
var keyOrdering = List[Int]()
var unorderedMap = Map[Int, String]()

unorderedMap += (1 -> "one")
keyOrdering :+= 1
```

**Edit**

You could implement your own `Ordering` and pass it to a `SortedMap` as well.

**Edit #2**

A simple example would be the following:

```
scala> import scala.collection.SortedMap
import scala.collection.SortedMap

scala> implicit object IntOrdering extends Ordering[Int]
     | def compare(a: Int, b: Int) = b - a
     | }
defined module IntOrdering

scala> var sm = SortedMap[Int, String]()
sm: scala.collection.SortedMap[Int,String] = Map()

scala> sm += (1 -> "one")

scala> sm += (2 -> "two")

scala> println(sm)
Map(2 -> two, 1 -> one)
```

The implicit Ordering is applied to the keys, so `IntOrdering` might be applied to a `SortedMap[Int, Any]`.

**Edit #3**

A self ordering DataType like in my comment might look this way:

```
case class DataType[T](t: T, index: Int)
object DataType{
  private var index = -1
  def apply[T](t: T) = { index += 1 ; new DataType[T](t, index)
}
```

Now we need to change the Ordering:

```
implicit object DataTypeOrdering extends Ordering[DataType[_]] {
  def compare(a: DataType[_], b: DataType[_]) = a.index - b.index
}
```

I hope this is the way you expected my answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `Ordering` and `SortedMap` a little more?

Comment: Thanks but it's incorrect: you sort the map by keys not by addition order in both examples

Comment: Yes, I said this is a simple example. You have to override the compare function with a suiting implemetation to do so.
For example could you create an own DataType with an automatically increasing index. That index you need to compare.

Answer (score 1):

After digging I've found out that there exists an immutable `ListMap` that behaves exactly as I want it, but according to [this table](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) its performance is just awfull. So I wrote a custom immutable implementation that should perform effectively on all operations except removal, where it performs linearly. It does require a bit more memory as it's backed by a standard `Map` and a `Queue`, which itself utilizes a `List` twice, but in the current age it's not an issue, right.

```
import collection.immutable.Queue

object OrderedMap {
  def apply[A, B](elems: (A, B)*) =
    new OrderedMap(Map(elems: _*), Queue(elems: _*))
}
class OrderedMap[A, B](
  map: Map[A, B] = Map[A, B](),
  protected val queue: Queue[(A, B)] = Queue()
) extends Map[A, B] {
  def get(key: A) =
    map.get(key)
  def iterator =
    queue.iterator
  def +[B1 >: B](kv: (A, B1)) =
    new OrderedMap(
      map + kv,
      queue enqueue kv
    )
  def -(key: A) =
    new OrderedMap(
      map - key,
      queue filter (_._1 != key)
    )
  override def hashCode() =
    queue.hashCode
  override def equals(that: Any) =
    that match {
      case that: OrderedMap[A, B] =>
        queue.equals(that.queue)
      case _ =>
        super.equals(that)
    }
}
```